# jquery if else statements - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Okay so I'm trying to set the value of one form field based on the value of another. Here's the code I have so far, not sure why it isn't working... Gotta love Fridays! lol

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var $price = 100;
var $price2 = 75;
var $price3 = 50;
var $price4 = 25;
$j(function () {
    $j( document ).ready(function() {
        $j('.addon-custom-price').val(4); 
    });
    $j('.qty').change(function () {
        var $this = $j(this);
        if ($this.val() > 100 || $this.val() <= 153) {
            $j('.addon-custom-price').val((parseFloat($price4 /$this.val())));
        }
        else if ($this.val() > 70 || $this.val() <= 100) {
            $j('.addon-custom-price').val((parseFloat($price3 /$this.val())));
        }
        else if ($this.val() > 40 || $this.val() <= 70) {
            $j('.addon-custom-price').val((parseFloat($price2 /$this.val())));
        }
        else if ($this.val() > 24 || $this.val() <= 40) {
            $j('.addon-custom-price').val((parseFloat($price /$this.val())));
        }
        else {
            $j('.addon-custom-price').val((parseFloat(0);
        }
    });        
});
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe use `$(this)` instead `$this`

Comment: How isn't it working? What is the output, and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: What kind of "not working" are we talking about here?  Error msg or wrong behavior please.

Comment: Also "$this.val() > 100 || $this.val() <= 153" will always be true as long as $this.val() is a number -- all numbers are either greater > 100 or <= 153. Did you mean to use && instead of ||?

Answer (score 0):

A second look at my code and I found the following errors:

When setting the value for the .addon-custom-price field with the snippet below, the math in my parseFloat was missing a space which probably caused some syntax errors

```
$j('.addon-custom-price').val((parseFloat($price /$this.val())));
```

They should looked like the following:

```
$j('.addon-custom-price').val((parseFloat($price / $this.val())));
```

The other error I found was in my closing **ELSE** statement:

```
$j('.addon-custom-price').val((parseFloat(0);
```

This is incorrect, dunno why I did it, but I did lol It should just simply be the following:

```
$j('.addon-custom-price').val(0);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about `if/else`.

Comment: Hi, Russ, you should edit your question to add more details. Differently from other sites, answers here are *only* to post solutions to the questions.